# How to extract 2 dates from a long string and put them in two different columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a data frame `df`:

```
df = data.frame(text = "M2O__LS___P_20160727T165346_20160808T165347_VV_ts_pan_fgdo_inte_dbrrt_IW9")
```

I want to have a new data frame `df2` that extracts the first (2016.07.27) and second (2016.08.08) dates from the `text` column of `df`.

The desired output data frame is:

```
     begin      end
1 20160727 20160808
```

I would specifically be interested in knowing a `tidyverse` approach to this problem (unless the base `r` is much more efficient)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Base R** Read the text separating by underscore, take the 7th and 8th columns, add the desired names and remove the T and everything after it.

```
DF <- read.table(text = df$text, sep  = "_")[7:8]
names(DF) <- c("begin", "end")
DF[] <- lapply(DF, sub, pattern = "T.*", replacement = "")
DF
##      begin      end
## 1 20160727 20160808
```

**1a)** Another base solution.

```
pat <- "_(\\d{8})T.*_(\\d{8})T"
strcapture(pat, df$text, list(begin = character(0), end = character(0)))
##      begin      end
## 1 20160727 20160808
```

**2) read.pattern**  pat is from (1a)

```
library(gsubfn)
read.pattern(text = df$text, pattern = pat, col.names = c("begin", "end"))
##      begin      end
## 1 20160727 20160808
```

**3) tidyr** pat is from (1a).

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df, text, c("begin", "end"), pat)
##      begin      end
## 1 20160727 20160808
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  transmute(begin = str_extract(.$text,"(?<=_)\\d{8}"),
            end = str_extract(.$text,"(?<=\\d_)\\d{8}"))
#>      begin      end
#> 1 20160727 20160808
```